# Problems with JQuery countdown timer plugin

Tags: jquery, timer, countdown

I'm using this plugin to create a simple countdown timer:
http://keith-wood.name/countdown.html

My issue is that the output of months as described in the layout reference doesn't seem to work.

This page: http://keith-wood.name/countdownRef.html#layout describes the output of months to be something like {ov} but that just gives me zero with the following code:

```
                $(function () {
                    var austDay = new Date();
                    austDay = new Date(2011, 6, 21);
                    $('#defaultCountdown').countdown({until: austDay, layout:'<b>{ov} {dl} and'+'{hn} {hl}, {mn} {ml}, {sn} {sl}</b>'});
                });
```

I'm trying to get it to spit out the months, days, hours and minutes with separators.

I'm using JQuery v.1.4.4

Answer (score 0):

Just update your layout string to the following:

```
layout:'<b>{on} {ol} {dn} {dl} and '+'{hn} {hl}, {mn} {ml}, {sn} {sl}</b>'
```

The letter 'o' is the code for month with this plugin, with the following 'n' for the data for that datetime part type, and the 'l' for the label of the datetime part type.